# Customer ID not found on Shopify CSV file

Tags: excel, csv, shopify

Customer ID,First Name,Last Name,Email,Accepts Email Marketing,Company,Address1,Address2,City,Province Code,Country Code,Zip,Phone,Accepts SMS Marketing,Total Spent,Total Orders,Note,Tax Exempt,Tags

'7271785759024,mehmet,bilgiç,,no,,,,,,,,+905343842739,no,0.00,0,,no,

Hi i want to transfer my shopify customers csv file to another shopify account. But i always get error.

error is: **Customer ID not found**

I get the same message for all customers on the list. so its not specific for a few customers. any idea how can i fix that?

I get the same message for all customers on the list. so its not specific for a few customers. any idea how can i fix that?

Comment: Without the code you are using there is essentially zero chance you will gate a useful answer. Add the code **as text** to your question text.

Comment: *...gate a useful answer.* --> *...get a useful answer.*

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. You cannot transfer a customer to another Shopify account without being very smart. First off, an ID from store will never match an ID from another, so there you go on your first problem. Second, you can import some semblance of customers into a different store, but you should also be aware that they have to activate their own accounts, so if you screw up the activation phase, your work is for nothing. Ensure you send them their "your account has been created, now activate it" emails.